# data table sorting no arrows shown - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I tried to set  sorting value which is  `this.requestsListTable.sortParams = sortKey;` and

```
this.requestsListTable.sortDirs = sortOrder;
```

but as you can see on the screenshot the sorting works and you can see the multi sort value but the arrow is not showing, what causes that issue ?  is the async request causes it ? and what is the possible solution. Thanks.

[image: table screenshot]

#ts code

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.currAcct = JSON.parse(this._storageService.getCurrAcct());

    this.isProjectTeamData = this.currAcct.isProjectTeamData;
    this.isRequestIntakeReadOnly = this.currAcct.isRequestIntakeReadOnly;
    this.isRequestIntakeSubmitter = this.currAcct.isRequestIntakeSubmitter;
    this.requestsListTable.dataSource = new MatMultiSortTableDataSource(this.sort, this.CLIENT_SIDE);
    // this.sort = new MatMultiSort();
    this.requestsListTable.nextObservable.subscribe(() => { this.initRequestsList(); });
    this.requestsListTable.sortObservable.subscribe(() => { this.initRequestsList(); });
    this.requestsListTable.previousObservable.subscribe(() => { this.initRequestsList(); });
    this.requestsListTable.sizeObservable.subscribe(() => { this.initRequestsList(); });
    this.getProjectIntakeDepartments();
    this.getRequestsCount();
    this.checkPageAccess();
    this.getUserData();
  }

     requestsListTable: TableData<any>;
    
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        fromEvent<any>(this.searchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup')
          .pipe(
            map(event => event.target.value.trim()),
            startWith(''),
            debounceTime(500),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            tap(search => {
              if (search) {
                this.requestsListTable.pageIndex =  0;
              }
              this.setDefaultFilters();
            }),
            switchMap(search => {``
              return this.filtersSubject.pipe(
                tap(() => {
                  this.initRequestsList();
                })
              );
            })
          )
          .subscribe({
            next: () => {
            },
            error: (err) => console.error(err),
            complete: () => noop
          });
      }
  
  initRequestsList() {
    const currAcct = JSON.parse(this._storageService.getCurrAcct());

    const sortKey = (this.requestsListTable.sortParams.length > 0) ? this.requestsListTable.sortParams : ['requestTitle'];
    const sortOrder = (this.requestsListTable.sortDirs.length > 0) ? this.requestsListTable.sortDirs : ['asc'];
    
    const isMyRequests = (this.selectedOption === '1') ? currAcct.userId : null;
    
    this.isLoading = true;

    this._projectIntakeService
      .getRequestsList(
        currAcct.accountId,
        isMyRequests,
        sortKey,
        sortOrder,
        this.searchInput.nativeElement.value || '',
        this.requestsListTable.pageIndex + 1,
        this.requestsListTable.pageSize,
        this.selectedDepartmentIds,
        this.selectedStatusIds
      )
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false)))
      .subscribe({
        error: (err) => this._notificationService.showError(err),
        next: (res) => {
          this.firstItemPosition = res.firstItemOnPage;
          this.lastItemPosition = res.lastItemOnPage;
          this.dataSource = res.items;
          this.lastItemOnPage = res.lastItemOnPage;
          this.totalItemCount = res.totalItemCount;
        },
        complete: _.noop,
      });
  }


getUserData() {
    this._userService.getUserProfile(this.currAcct.userId, this.currAcct.accountId)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          if (res.isSuccess) {
            const filteredAccounts = this.filterAccountsByName(res.data.userAccountDto, this.currAcct.accountName);
            this.projectIntakeSettings = JSON.parse(filteredAccounts[0].projectIntakeSettings);

            //request type
            this.selectedOption = (this.projectIntakeSettings.UserId) ? '1' : '2';

            //page
            this.requestsListTable.pageIndex = (this.projectIntakeSettings.Page) ? this.projectIntakeSettings.Page - 1 : 0
            this.requestsListTable.pageSize = (this.projectIntakeSettings.PageSize) ? this.projectIntakeSettings.PageSize : 10;


            // Check if sortKey and sortOrder are provided in projectIntakeSettings
            const sortKey = this.projectIntakeSettings.SortKey ? JSON.parse(this.projectIntakeSettings.SortKey) : ['requestTitle'];
            const sortOrder = this.projectIntakeSettings.SortOrder ? JSON.parse(this.projectIntakeSettings.SortOrder) : ['asc'];

            // Assign sortParams and sortDirs
            this.requestsListTable.sortParams = sortKey;
            this.requestsListTable.sortDirs = sortOrder;

          }
        },
        err => {
          AppUtils.errorHandler(err, this._notificationService, null);
        }
      )

  }
```

#html code

```
 <table
                      mat-table
                      [dataSource]="dataSource"
                      matMultiSort
                      [@animateStagger]="{value:'50'}"
                      (matSortChange)="requestsListTable.onSortEvent()"  
                      (contentChanged)="isLoading = false">

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="requestTitle" sticky>
                      <th mat-multi-sort-header="requestTitle" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Request Title</th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <div class="checkbox-container td-value-name">
                          <mat-checkbox matTooltip="{{ isNotAllowedBulk(element) ? 'Unable to batch approve' : '' }}"
                            [checked]="isSelected(element)" [disabled]="isNotAllowedBulk(element)" class="no-navigation"
                            color="primary" (change)="onChangeSelect(element, $event, 'request')"></mat-checkbox>
                          <div style="width:180px;" [matTooltip]="element.requestTitle" class="td-value-name request-title">{{
                            element.requestTitle?.length > 45 ? element.requestTitle.slice(0,45) + '...' : element.requestTitle }}</div>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="requestorName">
                      <th mat-multi-sort-header="requestorName" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Requestor Name</th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <div class="td-value-name">
                          {{element.requestorName}}
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>
```